# Social authentification django

Tags: python, django, python-social-auth

I am building a website using django, and I did a social auto using 'allauth', but the thing is, I can only login from my own facebook account where I have added the app in developers.facebook.com, well I want other users , to be able to login with their own facebook accounts.
Is there's another way than 'allauth', or should I make changes to it ?
I am a beginner in django.

Comment: It has nothing to do with `allauth`. You need to make your Facebook app live otherwise in dev mode only app authors or test users can use that app. Read more about it [here](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/apps/managing-development-cycle/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In `APP Review` tab  Make your facebook app **public** by clicking **Yes**.

and then **anyone can login using their facebook account** even from localhost beacuse facebook api allows localhost also unlike `google` or `twitter api`.

[image]